# The way Sat4j actually solves CNF clauses

Tags: sat, sat-solvers, conjunctive-normal-form, sat4j

I have two `.cnf` files containing CNF clauses. Both these files solve one problem, which means that the CNF clauses in the two files are the same, but the order of CNF clauses in each file is different. I've set `timeout = 1800s`, but **only one** `.cnf` file can solve that problem in 1800s, the other doesn't. Hence, I wonder if the order of CNF clauses in `.cnf` file affects the way Sat4j solve the problem or not.

I want to know more about the way Sat4j (Minisat) solves CNF clauses.

Comment: For such questions, sat4j provides a [list of references](https://www.sat4j.org/allabout.php). The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver#CDCL_solvers) is also a possible starting point.

Comment: @AxelKemper As far as I know, these documents don't mention this issue.

Comment: Yes. The references are meant to address your final question. Most If not all SAT solvers have a high degree of non-determinism. Therefore, the ordering of clauses may have a similar effect than a changed seed value of their random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

SAT solvers are *chaotic*, in the sense that they are sensitive to seemingly irrelevant input conditions (e.g., the order of the constraints, the random seed, the polarity of the variables). This follows from the fact that they try to solve hard problems. Often, only a couple of solutions exist in a huge search space of possible solutions. Or conversely, there exist only a couple of short resolution proofs in an even larger space of possible resolution proofs in case the problem is unsatisfiable. In both cases, the internal heuristics have to "get lucky" to find a solution/proof. Getting lucky depends on all input conditions, hence the performance differences observed when reordering certain CNFs.